# How to get $attachment->ID in custom functions

Tags: attachments

This is what I have now within an attachment theme template...

```
//GET THE URL OF THE ATTACHMENT
$parsed = parse_url( wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) );
$url = dirname( $parsed [ 'path' ] ) . '/' . rawurlencode( basename( $parsed[ 'path' ] ) );

//GET THE ATTACHMENT TYPE FOR ICON
$mtype = get_post_mime_type($attachment->ID); 
$mtypeicon = '';
if ($mtype == "application/pdf") {
    $mtypeicon = "<i class='far fa-file-pdf'></i>";
}
```

I'm happy with it.  It works. But now, I am in process of moving this code over into my functions.php so I can instead do an `add_action/do_action` sequence.  What is the right way to say `$attachment->ID` from within a custom function?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attachment ID, you need to get the post attachments using [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) with the `post_type` being 'attachment' and the `post_parent` being the ID of the post you're interested in getting the attachments from.

```
namespace StackExchange\WordPress;
function the_post( \WP_Post $post, \WP_Query $query ) {
  //* Get post attachments
  $attachments = \get_posts( [
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'exclude'        => get_post_thumbnail_id()
  ] );
  //* There can be more than one attachment per post, so loop through them
  foreach( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    //* Maybe do some sanity checks here
    $parsed = parse_url( \wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) );
    //* Do something useful with the parsed URL
  }
}
\add_action( 'the_post', __NAMESPACE__ . '\the_post', 10, 2 );
```

Above, I'm using the [`the_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/) action to get the post ID of the post parent. Depending on your use case, you could use another hook and [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/) to get the ID of the post parent.

Comment: This worked out perfectly and gave me a first time experience on extracting array data from get_posts().  Many thanks.